# DoReturn throws UnfinishedStubbingException

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Okay so I obviously didn't quite understood the difference between doReturn(...).when(...) and when(...).thenReturn(...) .

The thing is I when I have a class, where I annotate Mocks with @Mock and inject them with @InjectMocks in my class I want to test and I then use doReturn on one of these mocks I get an UnfinishedStubbingException. But when I use when(...).thenReturn(...) everything seems to work just fine. I thought doReturn is more advised, since it doesn't really call the method (which I guess when(...).thenReturn(...) doesn't to, since the field is a Mock.)

So here's an example:

```
doReturn(siteModel).when(siteService.getCurrentSite()) --> UnfinishedStubbingException

when(siteService.getCurrentSite()).thenReturn(siteModel) --> Works just fine
```

Answer (score 24):

The correct invocation is:

```
doReturn(...).when(whatever).theMethod()
```

And not `.when(whatever.theMethod())`.